# Ethereum how to transaction with rpc?

Tags: transactions, ethereum

I start geth client localhost, enter console, unlock account and send transaction.
`web3.personal.unlockAccount("0xe3d787588f28542a5938ca97cc1d6acb9278176d");
eth.sendTransaction({
    from: eth.coinbase, 
    to: "0xfbccf3222a38a145c955aaf8ac2c66c6270dac04", 
    value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), 
    gas: 21000
});`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJOGs.jpg)

Need to unlock account with input password, and pravite key save in keystore.

Json-rpc docs send transaction without password and private key.

`{"jsonrpc"=>"2.0", "id"=>2, "error"=>{"code"=>-32000, "message"=>"authentication needed: password or unlock"}}`

Return the error message. But I cannot found how to unlock account, because jsonrpc disable personal function.

Anyhow to send transaction without local geth node?

Answer (score 0):

1.first you should enable geth with --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal"
2.then

> curl http://localhost:8545 -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0xaddress", "password", 15],"id":67}'
>
> > finally
> >     you can use rpc to send eth

Answer (score 0):

You can unlock via console like @chuixue explained above or you can also start your geth node with your account unlocked adding these params:

```
./geth -unlock "0xe3d787588f28542a5938ca97cc1d6acb9278176d" --password ./password.txt
```

where password.txt contains the password for that account.